# Not triggering event inside init()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to trigger a event in order to display a success message on the screen. Notification event is properly working everywhere but when I try to trigger it inside init() function for the app, its not getting executed although the rest code inside that block is executed.

```
    $scope.init = function() {
        if (appUtils.groupCreated === true) {
           console.log("inside"); //getting printed
            $rootScope.$broadcast("notifyEvent", {
                type: "alert-success",
                message: "Server group is successfully created."

            });
           appUtils.groupCreated = false;            }
    };

    //HTML code 
   <div class="container" ng-controller="ServerController" ng-init="init()">
        <notification position="top" timeout="5000" class="myClass"></notification>
    </div>
```

**Notification Directive**

```
.directive("notification", function($interval) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        timeout: "@",
        position: "@"
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><div ng-repeat="notification in notifications" ng-show="displayNotification" class="alert alert-dismissible {{notification.type}} {{notificationPosition}}" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>{{notification.message}}</div></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.$on("notifyEvent", function(e, notifyObject) {
           $scope.displayNotification = true;
            console.log("notification");
            // if there are multiple messages
            if (notifyObject.messages && notifyObject.messages.length > 0) {
                $scope.notifications = notifyObject.messages;
            } else {
                $scope.notifications = [{
                    message: notifyObject.message,
                    type: notifyObject.type
                }];
            }

            if ($scope.position) {
                $scope.notificationPosition = "notify" + $scope.position;
            }

            if ($scope.timeout) {
                $interval(function() {
                    $scope.displayNotification = false;
                }, $scope.timeout);
            }
        });
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        scope.timeout = attributes.timeout;
        scope.position = attributes.position;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: you mean other `$rootScope.$on("notifyEvent", {})` doesn't get executed?

Comment: do you get any error in developer console? try putting a breakpoint at console.log statement. when it pauses there, execute the broadcast code block in console separately and see if it throws any error.

Comment: Where do you listen to the "notifyEvent"-event? Also, could you show more of the controller? Maybe its something with the $rootScope injection?

Comment: May be your `$on` code in not registered because the relative controller may not loaded when you're broadcasting

Comment: @Gustav I have added the code for directive. You can it.

Comment: I've never used `ng-init` before, but reading the documentation it seems it does not fit in where you're using it. Can't you just execute your init-function in the `ServerController`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit